# md-tooltip not working with marquee

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using md-tooltip in md-button and using marquee to display scrolling label of button. But md-tooltip just shows for a second and then disappears when I move mouse over the md-button. I have noticed that when I remove the marquee code md-tooltip is getting displayed properly. Tried using md-z-index, md-visible as well but no help. All the controls are added in section.

```
<section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap>
    <div ng-repeat="mybutton in allbuttons">
        <md-button class="md-fab">
          <div >
              <md-tooltip md-direction="top" md-visible="true">{{mybutton.buttontooltip}}</md-tooltip>
              <img ng-src={{mybutton.imagesource}} style="width:50px" />
          </div>
      </md-button>
      <div class="buttonLabel">
          <marquee scrollamount="1" style="float:left; font-size: 12px; width:70px; color: white; padding-right: 5em">
            <div>
                {{buttonlabel}}
            </div>  
          </marquee>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

my css for class buttonLabel is as below.

```
.buttonLabel {
        background-color: #080808;
            color:#EEE5E5;
            bottom: 2px;
            left: 520px;
            margin: 10px;
    }
```

Plucker link is below. If you remove marquee it will work fine.

https://codepen.io/naddy1/pen/eKbGVN

Please let me know if I am doing it the correct way?

Comment: have tried with static text for tooltip?

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale Yes tried static as well but no luck.

Comment: Can you produce a plucker?

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale added in original question. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKbGVN

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale  please use this link. https://codepen.io/naddy1/pen/eKbGVN

Comment: So you want to set tooltip on marquee tag hover?

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale I want the tool tip to behave as standard way on md-button hover. if you see the plucker md-tootip is getting disappeared in few miliseconds on md button hover. I am using marquee just for scrolling text.

Comment: unable to understand dear!

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale please try the link and move your mouse over the button. you will see that tooltip is not displayed properly.

Comment: yes its displaying to the bottom

Comment: it's just fading away in my case..I am checking in internet explorer 11.

Comment: Could you add screen shot?

Comment: screnshot will not help much as you can't see the cursor position..if you have Microsoft edge then also its not working there.I have tried on google chrome and its working fine there..